# $filter->getLabel() appending layered navigation filter URL when used in observer

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

I am using the `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` event to get the labels of the active filters of the layered navigation. I load the filters like this:

```
$activeFilters = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State')->getActiveFilters();
$labels = array();

foreach ($activeFilters as $filter) {
$labels[] = array('label'=> strip_tags($filter->getLabel()));
}
```

The problem is that the filter url is appended in double curly brackets to each value (this is the case for all values like attribute name, code, label etc.), so the values of my array look like this

```
[label] => XL{{http://www.mydomain.com/shopby/XL/}}
```

Anyone has an idea why this is happening and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have old version of this [navigation module](http://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html) installed:

To prevent it, please upgrade or de-activate the module.

Also you can just strip everything in curly brackets.

Comment: Thanx, this solved my problem. I am removing the URL with preg_replace, I will think about a future upgrade of the module.